# Write JUnit Test for binary search method with Comparable[]

Tags: java, junit

*Please note I'm a beginner*

I am trying to write a set of test cases for the following code:

```
int binarySearch(Comparable[] objArray, Comparable searchObj) {

        int low = 0;
        int high = objArray.length - 1;
        int mid = 0;

        //iterative binary search algorithm
        while (low <= high) {
            mid = (low + high) / 2;

            if (objArray[mid].compareTo(searchObj) < 0) {
                low = mid + 1;
            } else if (objArray[mid].compareTo(searchObj) > 0) {
                high = mid - 1;
            } else {
                return mid;
            }
        }
        //return target index position
        if (objArray[mid].compareTo(searchObj) > 0) {
            return mid;
        } else
            return mid + 1;
    }

    @Test
    public void testBinarySearch() {

        //Test for lower boundary of array
        BinarySearch ob = new BinarySearch();
        Comparable[] array = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
        int result = ob.binarySearch(array, 5);
        System.out.println("Index position should return 0. Result is:  " + result);


    }
```

As you can see, I've written the logic for my first test case and it is returning the correct result. However, I can't seem to figure out how to rewrite it as a JUnit test in a way that I can also write additional tests (such as test upper boundary of array).

I'm not sure whether I should be using Assert, or assertArrayEquals. I have never used JUnit before and may be overlooking something relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good beginning. Just stop thinking about printing, rather directly verify. Here you are your first test rewritten to junit:

```
@Test
public void testLowerBoundaryOfArray() {
    BinarySearch ob = new BinarySearch();
    Comparable[] array = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    int result = ob.binarySearch(array, 5);
    Assert.assertEquals("Index position should be as expected", 0, result);

}
```

Note that I also named the test after what it is testing, rather than stating that in a comment.

`Assert.assertEquals` has two or three parameters (the first one is optional testing step explanation). The second is the expectation and the third is the actual result. One could argue that in your case the expectation message is quite not needed, but I include it for complete demonstration of the API.

Comment: This is so helpful! Thank you. Additional question: is it the best form to write the individual tests like this? So the next one would be public void testUpperBoundaryOfArray() and follow the same syntax / setup?

Comment: @Giuseppe Depends on how you want to structure it. There is no problem to assert couple of times in the same method and the report will come in clean. I would rather create methods for specific things you think are to be tested e.g. testEmptyTreeSearch, testFullTree, testExistingElement, testSingleLineTree, testUpperBoundAboveMax, testLowerBoundBelowMax as well as couple of more in between test cases where I would assert elements around values you have chosen

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported the Junit lib in your project.

> import org.junit.Assert;

Then you can easly :

> Assert.assertEquals(expected,actual);

Where expected is the value you're expecting from you binarySearch , and the actual is the value which should return.